# How can I test in cypress the lengh of string should be less xxx character

Tags: cypress

How can I test in cypress the lengh of string should be less xxx character

```js
cy.get('[data-testid="textfield"]').type('Automation')
  .should('to.have.length.of.at.most(100)');
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to extract the value of the input with `.invoke('val')`

```js
cy.get('[data-testid="textfield"]')
  .type('Automation')
  .invoke('val')
  .should('have.length.lt', 100)
```